# Receiving 0 Acccuracy in MNIST CNN with Macbook M1 MPS

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, apple-m1

I am very new to deep learning and trying to run the Pytorch official example code on MNIST dataset

code: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/tree/master/mnist

I am using Macbook Pro M1, when the device variable in Pytorch is set to mps(line 107), I got an accuracy of 0% but I can see the loss is decreasing during training

> Train Epoch: 1 [56320/60000 (94%)]      Loss: 0.040613
> Train Epoch: 1 [56960/60000 (95%)]      Loss: 0.072618
> Train Epoch: 1 [57600/60000 (96%)]      Loss: 0.106226
> Train Epoch: 1 [58240/60000 (97%)]      Loss: 0.096637
> Train Epoch: 1 [58880/60000 (98%)]      Loss: 0.003050
> Train Epoch: 1 [59520/60000 (99%)]      Loss: 0.007105
>
> Test set: Average loss: 0.0481, Accuracy: 0/10000 (0%)

However, when I switch the device to cpu, everything works fine(but slower), got accuracy around 97%.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you perform inference of just a few samples on the M1 and determine if the results are not NaN, and generally make sense? 0% accuracy is odd, even random guessing should be ~10% for MNIST.

Comment: I have the same issue. And, I found that the result of `argmax` is extraordinary (I got very big negative number).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by `argmax()`. I think it is an unsafe `ops` when using `mps` device. In this case, you can use `.max(dim=1).indices` to get the correct results. More details can be found at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/92311 .